# Expected Value for the Number of Parts of a Random Partition (Considering Only a Portion of the Partition Spectrum)

Tags: combinatorics, number-theory, probability-theory, discrete-mathematics, integer-partitions

Let $n$ be a positive integer. If we take the set of all partitions of $n$ and choose a random partition from it (uniformly), then the expected value of the number of parts of this partition is a known result. The highest order term of the expected value is $\sqrt{n}\operatorname{Log}(n)$ (Kessler & Livingston, 1976).

Instead of the set of all partitions of $n$, I only want to consider $k \%$ of the total spectrum of partitions. Let $P^k(n)$ denote the set which contains $k \%$ of the total partitions of $n$. The partitions in $P^k(n)$ are chosen as follows. We begin with the empty set and add partitions one by one. At every step we choose to add a partition that has the smallest number of parts. We stop adding partitions once the set $P^k(n)$ contains the required $k \%$ of the total number of partitions.

I am interested in the partition in $P^k(n)$ that has the highest number of parts, call this $max\left(P^k(n)\right)$. Numerical experiment has shown that for large $n$, $\operatorname{max}\left(P^k(n)\right) \approx k \sqrt{n}\operatorname{Log}(nk)$. So for fixed $k$ and increasing $n$ we get $\operatorname{max}\left(P^k(n)\right) = \mathcal{O}(\sqrt{n}\operatorname{Log}(n))$.

Is there a way to apply Kessler and Livingston's result to the set $P^k(n)$, so that we get the expected value for the number of parts of partitions in that set? This would be incredibly helpful as it would be a lower bound for $\operatorname{max}\left(P^k(n)\right)$.

Comment: You can get the proper font and spacing for $\max$ and $\log$ using `\max` and `\log`. For operators that don't have a command of their own, you can use `\operatorname{name}`.

Comment: Apparently you mean the 1976 paper "The Expected Number of Parts of a Partition of $n$"? This is available online [here](http://gdz.sub.uni-goettingen.de/dms/resolveppn/?PPN=GDZPPN002479915).

Comment: @joriki Yes, that is the paper I was referring to.

Comment: Excuse me if this is a silly question -- I am new to this. :) Let $X =$ the number of parts in a random partition.  Then 1976 result is about the mean $E[X]$, while you're asking about the $k$-th percentile for a fixed $k$, am I right?  The 1976 paper (which I only vaguely understand) seems to use a standard technique of differentiating a generating function to find the mean.  Is there a similar technique for percentile statistics?  Nothing comes to my mind but I'm a newbie at generating functions.

Comment: [cont'd] Alternatively, are there known theories about families of distributions (indexed by $n$ here) s.t. the growth (w.r.t. $n$) of the mean is similar to the growth of the $k$th percentile?  E.g. consider the family $Binomial(n,p)$ - because of CLT, the leading terms are both linear.

Comment: @antkam Yes, you are correct - we are interested in the expected value of the number of  parts (and the highest number of parts) of a partition while only considering the $k^{th}$ percentile of the smallest partitions. It's not obvious how to alter the generating function to consider only the $^{ℎ}$ percentile.

Comment: To be precise, you are not asking about the "expected value of the number of parts of a partition".  You are asking about the highest number of parts in the partition.  This is exactly the $k$th percentile.  I still have no idea how to help though.  :(

Comment: @antkam I am interested in both of those quantities. It seems that there is little information on percentiles for partitions. To get an exact answer, I may need to go back to the drawing board and look at partitions that have a certain number of parts, rather than a fraction of the spectrum. Thanks for taking a look!

Comment: If the bounty expires without a good answer, let me suggest posting the question to mathoverflow.net

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is known that the number of partitions of $n$ with largest part $k$ is the same as the number of partitions into $k$ parts (see e.g. [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partition_(number_theory)#Restricted_part_size_or_number_of_parts)). Thus we can translate your question into asking about the size of the largest part of a (uniform) random partition. The asymptotic distribution of the largest part is given by the Erdős Lehner theorem ([1]) which states that ([2], equation 2.2)

$\begin{equation}
\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}P_n(\lambda \in \mathcal{P}_n : \frac{c}{\sqrt{n}}\lambda_1 − \log \frac{\sqrt{n}}{c}\leq x) = e^{−e^{−x}}
\end{equation}$, where $c=\frac{\pi}{\sqrt{6}}$.

Here $\mathcal{P}_n$ is the set of partitions of $n$, $P_n$ the uniform measure on $\mathcal{P}_n$, elements (partitions) of $\mathcal{P}_n$ are denoted by $\lambda$ ,and $\lambda_1$ denotes the largest part of $\lambda$. As an aside, this limiting distribution is known as the [Gumbel distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gumbel_distribution).

In particular, if we let $\lambda_1^{(k)}$ denote the largest part of the $k$th percentile partition (ordered in increasing order of largest part), set $e^{-e^{-x}} = k$, solve for $x$ and then for $\lambda_1$ using $\frac{c}{\sqrt{n}}\lambda_1 − \log \frac{\sqrt{n}}{c} = x$, we get $x = \log (\frac{1}{\log (1/k)})$ and $\lambda_1^{(k)} = \frac{\sqrt{n}}{c}\log (\frac{\sqrt{n}}{c\log (1/k)})$.

References:

1. P. Erdős, J. Lehner: The distribution of the number of summands in the partition of a positive integer. Duke Math. J. Vol. 8 (1941)
2. Zhonggen Su: [Asymptotic analysis of random partitions](https://pdfs.semanticscholar.org/0c8d/28b15cf31d06194b4fa9d76232f4f7aa70ec.pdf)