# Distribution of integer partitions by number of parts

Tags: integer-partitions

I imagine someone has studied this already so I'm just looking for resources: what sort of asymptotic behavior does the distribution of integer partitions of $n$ counted by the number of parts exhibit? Looking at the plots that WolframAlpha supplies for low-ish values (around 30), the distribution looks sort of like Tracy-Widom.

Comment: Does this answer your question: https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3670073/123905 ?

Comment: @EricTowers yes, thank you